# Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?

Tags: support, flags, comments, comment-flags

Usually if I flag a comment it takes some time for the flag to be reviewed before it either takes effect or is declined.

Today I flagged a few comments as "not constructive" and they disappeared (and were shown as "helpful" in my flag history) instantaneously (well 3 out of 4 on the same conversation did, and the 4th had the slower behavior I'm used to).

I'm pretty sure I'm not, like, transitioning from a boy to a man and discovering the true super strength of my latent comment flagging abilities (and, of course, finding out that my parents aren't actually my real parents, and that it is my destiny to carry out my true father's legacy as supreme ruler of planet Notconstructivon, etc.). So, purely out of curiosity, why did that happen? What was different about those comments / flags?

Comment: See [flagged comments disappear instantly … what's going on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121225/flagged-comments-disappear-instantly-whats-going-on) over on meta.se. Not ruling out superpowers, though, that'd be cool.

Comment: The other possibility I considered is maybe it depends on how hard I click the mouse button. I flagged those particular comments pretty hard.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Michael indicated in the comments, you flagged three comments that used variants on a particular obscenity. The system automatically deletes comments made like that, without needing the intervention of a moderator.

So, less superpowers and more *deus ex machina*.

Comment: Not only that but these are typically the easiest flags for us to handle, so even if it wasn't laced with obscenities this would probably be handled pretty fast.

Comment: @JasonC - Accept rate used to be shown publicly, which seemed like a good idea at the time (as an indication of hit-and-run askers), but it quickly devolved into people harassing others about accepting posts via comments. It got so bad that accept rate was hidden again and comments mentioning it became one-flag deleted. I can see an argument for turning that off now, since I think we're far enough from then that people aren't doing this anymore.

Comment: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773)

Comment: Note that the system also has automatic deletion criteria for "thanks" comments, not just offensive ones.

Comment: I still think it's superpowers.