# How come this flag handled instantly?

Tags: support, flags, comment-flags

I was reading this question [How can I profile my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3871311/3330969)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871334/3330969) and saw a comment below it. I find it offensive so flag it and flag got handled within next second.

Here is snapshot of my flag history for proof

> [image]

How come this flag handled instantly ?

Comment: Ah, I see what happened, you just clicked _really_ hard when submitting the flag.

Comment: @TimPost _really_ hard !!! what does this mean ? I just click the command button.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect. I was going to suggest a dup, but that one was about comment flags, while this was for a question flag.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: This one is also for a comment flag.

Comment: @ruakh: Ah, right, I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Certain kinds of flags are self-fulfilling if enough of them gather up. Anywhere you can say 'offensive' or 'spam' by raising a flag, a sufficient number of them will cause the community user to just delete it until a mod has had a chance to look at it.

You just happened to be the last flagger, so the effect was instantaneous.

There are also instances where a *single* flag can cause a comment to be removed, for instance if it contains profanity that we don't *outright* block.

Helps keep things clean without leaving all the rubbish around for moderators to have to deal with.

Comment: Ah, got it, that means few of other users like me too did flag on it. Actually this happens first time with me, so I get surprised.

Comment: @Kedarnath Yes, it's a nice feature of the system. If there's something bad on the site, the community can handle it themselves, it doesn't stay there bothering people until a diamond moderator can handle it.