# Flagging comments for "serious" problems

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, tooltips

When a user currently wants to flag a comment, there is this tooltip:

[image: Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention]

The use of the word "serious" makes the process of flagging comments sounds like something really terrible has happened and it must be dealt with right now by a moderator.

However, after you click the flag button, the given default options do not seem to qualify as being *serious* problems. Among them, "not constructive", "obsolete" or "too chatty" are, in my view, not serious problems but simply problems. This would be true for "rude or offensive" but that is not the only default choice.

Feature request: I suggest the removal of the word "serious" from that sentence, making the tooltip:

> Flag this comment for problems or moderator attention

I feel it gives a wrong impression and could let users to believe wrong assumptions about when they should flag comments. It could actually prevent them from flagging, when in fact they should, only because it isn't "serious" enough for them, leaving behind a pile of unconstructive comments.

Do note that, [from the official guidance of when to flag comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365), you can flag "anything that's not really relevant" as "chatty". Is that a serious problem?

Comment: There is the issue of users flagging because they think the comment is technically wrong, showing "serious problem" might refrain some (hopefully) to do so.

Comment: I think the word "serious" is in there because for whatever reason you flag the comment, what you're really doing is saying it needs to be removed. I think they just want it clear that if you don't think whatever the problem is warrants deletion then you shouldn't flag it.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with this suggestion.

Moderator flags *should* only be used as last resort:
Issues that can't be solved with actions normally available to users. Issues that *have* to be handled.

A single chatty comment could be considered *"Not constructive"*, but doesn't necessarily warrant a mod flag, for example.

*"Serious"* is in there to dissuade users from flagging comments that are kinda, sorta, maybe, possibly off-topic.

---

My reasoning behind this is as follows:

For the pre-defined flags, flagging a comment means:
*"This comment should be **deleted** because <reason>"*
Flagging a comment has two possible outcomes:

- The comment gets deleted.
- The flag gets declined / disputed.

If the issue with the comment isn't *serious enough* to warrant deletion, the comment shouldn't be flagged.
(With a possible exception for a mod flag for cases not covered by the default flags)

Comment: Is this comment not constructive enough?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: It may not be, but it doesn't require moderator intervention. In other words: Not a _serious_ problem ;-)

Comment: This is not what [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365) suggests. Chatty is "anything that's not really relevant". Is that serious?

Comment: The OP is pointing out that the *tooltip* that comes up when the mouse hovers over the flag icon is saying "Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention". This tooltip does not make the distinction between using the canned flags, which we are quite fine to use for routine things like "not constructive" comments  vs using a custom flag (which you seem to refer to as a "mod flag"), which should be reserved for serious problems.

Comment: I was always under the impression that _all_ comment flags went through a moderator queue. That isn't the case?

Comment: @Cerbrus That's the case.

Comment: So, if all of those flags go through a moderator queue, shouldn't they all be used sparingly for serious issues that _require_ moderator intervention?

Comment: Only moderators can delete comments made by others. There's no guideline anywhere, and I've never seen a moderator say "You know. If there is only *one* chatty comment under a post. You should *not* flag it because that's a bad use of our time." I've routinely flagged such comments (the biggest offender being "thanks") and routinely have had such flags found helpful. (The advice I've seen from moderators is when there is a whole slew of comments that should be removed, flag the post with a custom flag rather than flag each comment individually.)

Comment: I see. You're reading too much into a simple example, taking that example literally. What I'm trying to say there: Consider whether the case is serious enough to _require_ a moderator to step in, or whether it's just a (single?) harmless comment.

Comment: There are currently no actions available to users to handle comments. Except adding another comment, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Or ignoring the comment chain. Letting it die out is an option too.

Comment: @Cerbrus i think there are exceptions, where multiples of some of the flags may result in the comment getting deleted immediately rather than going through the queue. Here's another case: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect

Comment: Guys, once again, what I'm saying is: Don't flag comments that aren't clearly off-topic, offensive, spam, etc. If it's not that big of a problem, if it's not a _serious_ issue, if it doesn't _absolutely_ have to be removed, don't flag it. Technically, _"Thanks, this solved my problem, I'm accepting this answer!"_ is chatty, but not a serious problem, for example.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's just not what moderators tell us about when to use flags. Whenever the mods have gone at length about flags, they've never said hold off flagging the chatty stuff because it is not *serious*.

Comment: So, mods are telling us to flag comments that don't need to be removed? No they're not.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying (you probably read before my edit).

Comment: @Louis: But have they explicitly stated that minor issues _must_ be flagged? That mods didn't say you shouldn't (source?), doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I see it as a guideline myself. I flag when I see something *too* chatty ("thanks", "+1", "I love you"), I don't go looking for chatty comments because sometimes they're not without value. Some people need to read something nice to not assume they're being "attacked".

Comment: @Cerbrus Look, the interface *invites* us, by having an explicit option for it, to flag chatty comments. And proper flagging has been discussed repeatedly on Meta, at length. If there was some distinction to be made between those situations where using the "too chatty" flag *is* warranted because presumably the problem is "serious", and those situations it is *not* warranted because the problem is not serious, I would have expected the moderators to talk about it. Just like whenever there's a discussion about the proper use of NAA, the issue of "does it *look* like an answer?" comes up.

Comment: @Louis: Do you agree that there's a difference between: _"Thanks, this answered my question"_ and _"Gee, the weather is good, today"_, in regards to how "Chatty" it is? Do you agree that the first example really doesn't harm the site, while the second one really should be removed? Both could be considered chatty, but the first one isn't a problem (If it stays at that).

Comment: @Cerbrus The difference is theoretical. In practice, I've always treated both comments as worthy of being flagged and never had a moderator decline such flag.

Comment: Then that's where our disagreement comes from. That example is why I think the _"serious"_ in the flag popup should stay. I'm curious how mods would respond to the example.

Comment: The "Can a machine be taught to flag?" question actually has some pretty good statements to make on comment flagging value, especially Brad Larson's answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280554/424903