# What should be done if OP is swearing in comments?

Tags: discussion

I answered this question and deleted as soon as I realized I posted the wrong answer i deleted it
I also commented on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645512/broadcast-listener-intent-for-detecting-calls?noredirect=1#comment60884958_36645512 and the OP `abbie` started swearing .

At first he posted a swearing in first comment , and then i posted what? so as to understand if i misunderstood what he meant, but then i figured he was swearing definitely so i flagged and now he posted another comment swearing once again.

What should be done in this scenario??

Comment: You already mentioned you flagged these comments, and it seems they are gone now. So what else?

Comment: i just wanted to know if there is anything other than flagging that we can do, otherwise users can keep swearing us in comments

Comment: @ankitagrawal if a user continues to be abusive a moderator will give them a time out if necessary. Just flag and forget :)

Comment: ok, i see that is how it works, i was just puzzled to see even after me flagging his first post he sweared again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> At first he posted a swearing in first comment , and then i posted
>   what? so as to understand if i misunderstood what he meant, but then i
>   figured he was swearing definitely so i flagged and now he posted
>   another comment swearing once again.
>
> What should be done in this scenario??

Flag inappropriate comments and move on. Moderators will review and delete them as necessary, they might even suspend the user if they do a lot of it.

Point being this isn't worth your energy beyond flagging it and moving on.

Comment: the whole point of this question is there a way other than flag to respond to these kind of comment, now i see that is not the case, ty for the help

Comment: I would add that for [seven dirty words](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect#comment251074_266162) comment flags even take effect immediately and stuff gets deleted without waiting for moderator