# What can we do when someone uses bad language to answer your question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, behavior

I just saw on Stack Overflow that someone was using bad language, may be just for fun, on a good question. What can we do about this?

Comment: Editing out *rude/ abusive* stuff is not the right solution here. A rude/ abusive flag should be raised. That person might have left several such comments on different posts. Mods will look into it and take appropriate action :). As @MartijnPieters points out, it is OK to edit out coarse language

Comment: Side note : The flag that you raised has been handled. I don't think  "*delete your account*" is a *funny statement*

Comment: Aww, you should have deleted *their* account, @TheLostMind.

Comment: @TheLostMind: editing out some coarse language is fine, provided there is a proper question or answer there. When the community can simply fix the post by removing an adjective here or there then that doesn't require moderator intervention or a -100 penalty to the post.

Comment: Of course, if the language is targeting the OP of a question or other post (in a comment or answer), rather than the world (or a piece of code) in general, then flagging is probably the right course of action.

Comment: @CodyGray - They wouldn't have lost much :P

Comment: I love that the answer in question attacked the OP for not knowing JavaScript... and then suggested that he learn JavaScript from w3schools. If that was a troll within a troll... I'm impressed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the comment or answer is trying to troll the OP, you can **flag** it.

For answer: the **flag** hyperlink is under the answer then select the "rude or abusive" option.
For comments: in beginning of the each comment you can see the **flag** option then select the "rude or offensive" option.

The moderator or reviewer will review the comment/answer and they can remove that.

Comment: Also note that spam/rude/abusive are all nuke flags.  They down vote the post (if you have not done so already) and if the post gets 6 such flags community locks and deletes it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, the flags downvote the post _even if_ you've downvoted already. I noticed this on some spam posts I spotted on MSE recently.

Comment: @Kendra Oh wow.  Hadn't seen that before.  I'll test next time smoke detector posts.

Comment: @NathanOliver Now that I think about it, it could just be really convenient timing... But I remember it on my last two on MSE and a recent flag from review on SO main. I would still bet money on it always auto-downvoting.

Answer (score 24):

If the bad words are incidental to the answer

> Here's how to fix the @#%$ that this company created [code example here]

Just edit them out

> Here's how to fix the **mess** that this company created [code example here]

Rude/abusive flags are for when the person is *attacking other people*. Please note that there's a real-time monitor that catches bad words. Actual attacks on other people don't live long around here.

Comment: "there's a real-time monitor that catches bad words" Are you talking about [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector)? Or is there a separate system used by moderators/employees to keep an eye on expletives?

Comment: @dorukayhan I mean SD. Notifies Charcoal, SOCVR and a few others as the posts come in

Comment: I'd go further and ask the OP to edit that since "heres how to fix" doesn't help explain how it fixes the issue at all (I understand that this is a simple example)

Comment: *"Just edit them out"* - I'd rather they simply be left alone. This is a professional site, not a nursery. If some contributors choose to swear, that's on them; I see no value in censoring bad language, and if the person whose post you're censoring feels that you've changed their meaning or tone in an important way then you'll have done harm and caused conflict where none was necessary.

Comment: Most often, curses are offensive to certain groups though. When humans create curses, they deliberately pick words that are the most political incorrect. It can be quite subjective to filter out which ones that are offensive to some people. Better then to simply not allow curses, than starting to censor them on case-by-case basis.

Comment: @MarkAmery - agreed, to some extent. While I personally know all the words and can spell them correctly, can use them in context, and have either been to or done pretty much all of them, that doesn't mean that those words are reasonable in a public forum. On the other hand, the earlier suggestion that the word "nonsense" should be edited out is, ahem, excessive. Back in the days of Usenet there was a standard of discourse, which was: A) be not excessively annoying; B) be not excessively annoyed.

Comment: @Lundin - *"Most often, curses are offensive to certain groups though"* - I was going to reply "that's bullshit", but my pet cow was offended.

Comment: @Lundin: slippery slope. One man's curse is the next woman's common remark. (I've worked for women who swore like sailors. Personally, having been a sailor I wasn't offended, but I did find it surprising).

Comment: @MarkAmery What's your point? Curses can easily be racist, sexist or offensive to certain religious groups. The problem with having a lax policy is that it becomes hard to draw the line between acceptable curses and unacceptable.

Comment: @BobJarvis That's the point I was making. Just because you don't find a particular word offensive, it doesn't mean that others don't.

Comment: @MarkAmery They should be edited out precisely *because* this is a professional site. Words like those don't help the question or answer, and they generally lower the level of discourse. I mean, the same logic applies to someone who rants about, say, Microsoft and then gives an otherwise good answer. The rant doesn't help the answer. Are you saying we shouldn't edit those out either? The word here is **tactfulness**. There's always a better way to say it. [That's why there's automation for the removal of those words](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161)