# When do "No longer needed" flags get resolved instantly?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I'm a fan of recent the comment-flag union: there's now just one button I need to hit for most of the comments I end up flagging. Instead of deciding between "Obsolete" and "We never really needed this *+1 THANKS SO MUCH* comment to begin with", I can just flag them both as "No longer needed".

But I've noticed recently that when I flag a comment as "No longer needed", sometimes the comment is removed instantly, and the flag is marked as "helpful" instantly in my profile. I don't remember this ever happening before the union - is this something new?

At first glance it sounds like [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/625403), but that question's answer talks about obscenity. The comments I've been flagging haven't been obscene or begging for upvotes or whatever, as that answer suggests could be the cause. The most recent one was just something like "Thanks for your help": polite but obviously useless to any future visitors referred by Google. Is there perhaps a regex like the obscenity detector that detects "useless noise" in comments to expedite their deletion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there are a few expressions that catch common patterns that aren't really *off-putting* so much as they are annoying *in bulk*. These vary a bit by site, but "thanks" is active most places - it's nice to be thanked, but once you've seen it - and especially when these comments sit around pushing out more informative comments - then it's handy to be rid of them without involving a moderator.

Right now, these expressions are few and fairly conservative; now that we've finally done the flag-revamp I'm hoping to ramp up the coverage here quite a bit in the coming months.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354145/4342498) shows that a comment was deleted by a single flag.  Is that expected?

Comment: Yes it is, @Nathan

Comment: OK.  Just didn't know if a single flag was intentional.