# Is there a way to see why my comment was deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

Today I posted a comment, and came back in a few minutes to find that it had been deleted. I'd like to find out why so I can adjust my future commenting behavior. Is there any way to find out, without resorting to asking moderators?

Comment: Nope, you can only ask a moderator or check if your comment contained any of the immediate deletion swearwords or *Thanks.....* or *Please accept my answer*

Comment: Not an automatic way. You could include the comment in this question and have the community speculate what the reason could have been. Sometimes the moderator who deleted it also happens to see the meta question here and posts an answer explaining their decision.

Comment: Do you remember what the comment was?  We could help to tell you if we think if it is okay or not.  Otherwise only people with diamonds will know.

Comment: I flagged it, but it was kind of an accident. I flag comments requesting people to post their comments as answers if the comments have been there a while. In my opinion, I don't think there's anything wrong with comments like that initially, I just think they become obsolete, because either the person already did it, or we can assume they aren't going to. In this case I didn't notice how recent the question and comment were until it was too late. Sorry about that!

Comment: I understand in a way that moderating is necessary, but I just got one answer deleted and it was a pretty good answer. It indeed only included links to the solution but I then corrected the mistake by pasting the code, but my answer was still deleted. Ths is just ridiculous, because from my answer you could see a quite some effort and research has been put into it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No biggie! Glad you're out there cleaning things up. :)

Comment: @AlexRebula: Why are you picking here of all places to complain about that? This question is about a *comment* getting deleted, not an answer. Two completely different beasts. You'd have better luck posting a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Acknowledged. :) Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @AlexRebula: If your answer was deleted *after* having been edited into shape, that sucks. You should be able to undelete it yourself, and hopefully no one will contest it having seen your edit.

Comment: Thank you for the info @BoltClock. I tried that, but could not find it. It is OK. A new lesson learned. :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No; the only context available is in the form of flags on your comment, surrounding comments, or the post itself, which are only visible to moderators. The idea behind this is that getting a comment deleted isn't a big deal and you shouldn't worry too much about it (though I can understand if you're trying to understand and learn — for that I recommend perusing [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), under "When should I comment?" and "When *shouldn't* I comment?").

But since you're here, I looked at the comment you were referring to (which you appear to have reposted):

> You're absolutely right. @MarkBaker, could you post your answer as an answer so I can accept it?

and it looks like your comment was deleted by a single "no longer needed" flag. Probably because of the word "accept", since comments containing that word are usually requests to accept an answer, and for that reason are eligible for deletion by a single flag.

Presumably your comment was flagged because someone else mentioned Mark Baker's comment in their own answer (albeit in passing), or they simply flagged it because they believe such requests are unnecessary anyway. I can't ascertain this either since the comment was deleted without moderator involvement — I can only speculate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Your theory makes a lot of sense. I still kind of wish I could see comment deletion flags in my profile somewhere... I get that it might cause more more upset users than is worth it, though.

Comment: Note to self : Never explain why your still-helpful comment is not posted as an аnswer, nor state that this аnswer has flows, nor [...] using the word `аnswer`. That might be a funny game ;-)

Comment: *The idea behind this is that getting a comment deleted isn't a big deal and you shouldn't worry too much about it*.  The big dealness of a deleted comment is in the eye of the beholder, not in the eye of stackoverflow or in the eye of the moderator that deletes it. Deleting any user content with no notification that it was done, no rationale anywhere, no trace of it in any history is completely counter to the generally transparent scheme that SO uses elsewhere (edit history, voting history, etc...) and seems completely out of character.

Comment: I can say that when my content is deleted without any notification or recorded history or rationale (and thus discovered by me somewhat accidentally), it feels horrible and feels like arbitrary censoring.  Suddenly makes me not trust StackOverflow as much as I used to (makes me wonder what other content has been deleted).  For context, I've been here 7+ years and provided over 10K answers.  I thought this was a pretty transparent place. Suddenly doesn't feel quite so.  There should be both a record and a notification.

Comment: @jfriend00: I agree that the site could do a whole lot more to be transparent about deleting comments versus just doing it silently as if the comment was never made to begin with, and I've also felt the sting of seeing my content gone. But since you've been here 7+ years, I'm not sure why you're only having trust issues now - the "comments are ephemeral, second-class citizens that get cleared in the hundreds a day" narrative has been touted for quite a while, all over meta, to the point of being a tired meme (that, yes, some people do try to abuse to justify deleting comments willy nilly).

Comment: @jfriend00: Nevertheless, if you've had comments deleted that were neither obsolete, chatty nor rude, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: @BoltClock - Because the concept of no-notification, no transparency comment deletion is new to me.  In 7+ years, I've never been aware of it happening to me and did not know SO does it. I'd like to think that's because I generally write useful comments, but I think there also must be a change in behavior of some moderators or some automated behavior that changed recently .

Comment: The context is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373381/are-some-comments-automatically-deleted-now.  That question referred me here.

Comment: @jfriend00: The most significant change I can think of is that comment flagging was made much more discoverable and accessible to users recently - through things like revamping the comment flagging options, and making the upvote and flag buttons highly visible. FWIW, the UI we get for auditing edited/deleted comment history is pretty heavy and I wonder how much of that could be distilled to users after removing personal details from flags, etc. There's also the issue of bulk deletions, and complicated cases not adequately addressed by a simple deletion reason.

Comment: @BoltClock - That seems likely.  Perhaps more comments are getting flagged and then mods are hitting the delete button more based on that.  FWIW, I don't think SO should have no-notification content removal as it goes against the otherwise good transparency that the rest of the site has (with notifications and change history nearly everywhere else) and suddenly seems very big brotherish.  With no notification and no reason, there's zero chance for anyone to learn what they did wrong and adapt their behavior which should be a goal.  All it does it make people mad or mistrusting of the site.

Answer (score 2):

This same issue was brought up back in 2014 ([Please notify users when their comment is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted)) and the consensus is that comments can be deleted without any reason because they are not regarded as important.

Thousands of comments are deleted by mods on a daily basis, and they don't need a reason to delete any of the comments. Comments can be deleted if it's seen as vulgar, offensive, spammy, or as adding nothing to the conversation.

If you want to the guidelines on how to post better comments, please refer to the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Thousands a day is a... bit of a stretch. I'd say hundreds. I also get the feeling your definition of "reason" is different because "seen as vulgar, offensive, spammy, or as adding nothing to the conversation" all seem to me like reasons for deleting a comment.