# How many "No longer needed" flags does it take for a comment to be auto-deleted?

Tags: support, comment-flags

I just flagged a comment "no longer needed" and was quite surprised when it disappeared immediately. I would have expected I was the first person to flag it, as it was on an answer of mine from earlier today, addressed to me, and until just before I flagged it I hadn't had a chance to respond. (And I can't imagine anyone flagging it as unfriendly or anything like that, it was constructive, polite, and helpful.)

The comment was something like (from memory):

> I think it's the index of the entry, not the index of the `"R:"`. The accepted answer and the `conversation.indexOf(message)` both make it look like that.

It seems to have been auto-deleted by reaching some threshold. How many "no longer needed" flags does it take to auto-delete a comment?

Comment: That's probably due to a keyword or key sentence (such as _Thank you_), not due to a specific number of NLN flags.

Comment: It generally takes 3 flags, but as Erik mentioned, you can also instantly delete comments if there are certain words in it (not sure exactly what they are).

Comment: @ErikA - Thanks, the content of the comment didn't fit the usual things I would think would cause that. It was something like "I think it's the index of the entry, not the index of the substring. The accepted answer and the `some code was here` both seem to say that." The only possible key word/phrase I could think of would be "accepted answer."

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle - Thanks, I thought I remembered 3 for certain flags (unfriendly, spam) but wasn't sure if it varied by flag, etc.

Comment: No, in terms of deletion they all work the same.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle - Thanks again. Do you happen to have a source for that? (Without going to too much trouble, it's not worth spending an even vaguely significant amount of your time on.)

Comment: I saw it somewhere on MSE, I'll go try and dig it up...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196435/how-is-it-possible-that-a-single-user-who-is-not-a-moderator-can-delete-a-commen

Comment: Pretty sure "accepted answer" is exactly the phrase that triggered the instant nuke.

Comment: Erik is correct, you were the only flagger, and it got auto-nuked because it contains a trigger word.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is not a duplicate, however. That question only addresses one-flag nuking, and its answer fails to mention that multiple flags can nuke a comment that doesn't contain a trigger keyword. This question is more general and doesn't explicitly mention one-flag nuking.

Comment: [Probably because of the word "accept"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354145).

Comment: See also [contains a common cuss word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121226).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work), comments generally require three flags to be automatically deleted, or more if the comment has been upvoted (one extra for every three upvotes, rounded up).

However, if the comment contains one of a set of specific trigger keywords, it will be automatically deleted, regardless of score. The list of trigger keywords is undisclosed, but a moderator can confirm whether or not it was automatically deleted as a result of a trigger keyword or by multiple flags by checking to whom the deletion is attributed to (if it's a user, it was 1-flag keyword-deleted; if it was the Community user, it was by multiple flags).