# What happens if a comment is flagged "no longer needed"?

Tags: discussion, comments

I often flag comments as "no longer needed" when the question has been edited in a way so the comment doesn't make anymore sense.

So what does actually happen with such comments:

- Is the comment author notified?
- Is the comment deleted automatically when it has been flagged "no longer needed" more then n times?
- Is the comment put in some moderator review queue?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Is the comment author notified?

No. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126787)

> Is the comment deleted automatically when it has been flagged "no longer needed" more then n times?

Comments are soft deleted after after being flagged `3 + score/3` times, where score is the number of up votes a comment has received. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365)

Certain heuristics are used (such as presence of bad language) that reduce the number of flags needed to auto delete. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99853)

> Is the comment put in some moderator review queue?

If not automatically deleted for one of the above reasons, the comment ends up in a moderator review queue.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, even single comment flag [sometimes take immediate effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/839601) depending on whether there are some... magic words in the comment

Answer (score -7):

> Is the comment author notified?

No.

> Is the comment deleted automatically when it has been flagged "no longer needed" more then n times?

Yes (see discussion in comments).

> Is the comment put in some moderator review queue?

Yes.

Comment: Re. the second question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353810/2301450

Comment: @Andy [An employee confirms that formula for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags?lq=1#comment388189_138168). And there are [1-flag rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238835/what-is-the-se-version-of-seven-dirty-words) for comments with specific content, like WHYT.