# Prevent useless/no longer needed comment before they get posted

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags

We all know that there is a lot of not needed comments that simply add noises or tend to transform a post to a chat. My concern here is about a particular type of comments:

> Comments that we flag as "no longer needed" and get **automatically deleted**.<sup>[ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353809/when-do-no-longer-needed-flags-get-resolved-instantly)</sup>

Since the system is able to detect such comments as useless why it doesn't do this when the user is about to post them? Most of these comments are usually "Thank you" comments and the idea would be to popup a message to the user to prevent him from posting them.

I know that the comment section already contains a placeholder to indicate that we should *Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.* but considering the amount of "thank you" comment I see each day, few users are reading this message *(not to say nobody)*

**Is such feature really useful?**

This will at least block some useless comments and prevent users to actively repeating them. It will somehow educate new users to avoid such comments and of course, we will have fewer comments to flag.

---

Again, the purpose of this feature is not to create a complex algorithm to read the user mind and detect if the comment he will post is not relevant. It's only about comments that the system already detects and deletes automatically. Why not doing the detection earlier to prevent them?

A similar feature is the one that prevents the asker from using some pattern in the title and oblige him to change before posting the question.

Comment: [ask me how that went over the last time I tried it...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments)

Comment: Which is the reason, regex is a pretty lousy way to implement AI.  Maybe they'll gain confidence some day that the smarter code is reliable enough and fast enough for every single comment without making the machine keel over.  I kinda doubt it.

Comment: @Shog9 well, this one was about the +1/-1 thing but actually I am talking about the one that the system will delete automatically when we flag .. so if they are removed then why we don't prevent them? I mean the detection is already there but a bit late IMO

Comment: @HansPassant I am not asking to implement it, it's already implemented because when you flag the comments they get deleted automatically. So why we don't detect them at post time instead of flag time

Comment: Taking another stab it: to have the machine do it up front, it needs to be 99.9% accurate at detecting snark to avoid creating a very large number of ticked-off users.  Might miss a few 9s there, Shog9 knows what that looks like.  And fast enough to handle the many, many comments that get posted.  Forcing users to flag significantly cuts down the accuracy requirement and majorly on the volume.

Comment: @HansPassant here is both situation : (1) "I can post a comment and it will get deleted automatically by the system and I don't know this and I will continue posting such comments"  (2) "The system will prevent me to post comment that it will delete anyway, so I know this and will no more post the commnets" ... I think (1) is causing more harm because users don't know their comments are getting deleted but the (2) will tell them that the comment will indeed get deleted so better don't post it.

Comment: Popup a little confirmation box with "_posting "thank you" will cost you 1 reputation point, are you sure you want to post this comment?_"

Comment: @TemaniAfif: "*It's only about comments that the system already detects and deletes automatically.*" There are no comments that are automatically detected and deleted. There are only comments which are automatically deleted *after being flagged*. You misunderstood the quoted sentence. The detection is *manual*, as it requires that someone choose to flag it. If nobody does, then the comment is fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas no I didn't missunderstand the quoted sentence because I wrote this sentence (the ref was only used for people that probably don't know this and need to understand what is happening) and  it's clear I think. I simply didn't repeat the same sentence but I meant the comments that system detect and delete automatically after flagging and was wondering if we cannot use the detection feature earlier.

Comment: @TylerH but there is nothing to invest, that's why I was asking .. the feature is somehow there. It's only about changing the flow a bit. Instead of running the algorithm at flagging time we run it at post time.

Comment: @NicolBolas the detection isn't *manual*, the flag is *manual* and not all the flagged comment you think useless are automatically deleted. Only some that the system *detect*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Even if they could just apply the exact same check before posting rather than after flagging, that would still require effort, bug checking, unit testing, code writing, etc. and as Shog has shown (and Travis' answer, too), similar things have not worked out that well in the past.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: "*the detection isn't manual, the flag is manual*" The flag is how the system knows the comment is inappropriate. The automatic deletion is ultimately triggered by the flag. I don't know how that can be described as anything other than "detection".

Comment: @TemaniAfif As those comments happen in the first place, "It will somehow educate new users"  seems to me to be an unrealistic expectation. The way many new users get educated is by commenting "Thanks! That works!" and *then* having how to accept an answer explained.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this could be done at the same time, while posting such comment they get the message about how to accept the answer. Honestly I stopped *educating* people that comment to my answer saying *thanks* by telling them *please accept the answer instead*. I flag and move on.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't find stats about the impact of that change in the long term? The only one I've found is this one https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/792066

Comment: You was asking why [mine proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398451/1997232) is not a duplicate. The critical point is this: *"prevent him from posting them"*. I don't want to prevent user posting "thanks". He can. And he can ignore message. As many times as he want. Less intrusive. I don't want to prevent user, I want to give them information, teach them.

Answer (score 17):

The feature to automatically delete comments containing a blacklisted word with one flag was specifically designed to account for the fact that *lots* of comments will contain blacklisted words and still be good comments.  Preventing anyone from ever posting a comment with, for example, the word "accept" in it would be absurd.  It could never work.

But comments containing those blacklisted words are *more likely* to be problematic, so rather than three people needing to think it's bad, one is enough.  This ensures that comments no one considers inappropriate can still be helpful, while greatly expediting moderation of actually bad content.  Preventing all of those *good* comments, just to avoid one person having to flag the bad comments (or worse, forcing everyone, good and bad posters alike, to subvert the word filters while still posting the same content).

Comment: I am only talking about comments that the system automatically delete on flag request ... not about blacklisted or contain or nothing .. If the system is deleting them automatically so why we allow them? either the system should stop doing this as it seems to be doing harm or we simply do this when the user post the comment

Comment: @TemaniAfif The comments that the system deletes on a single flag are those that contain a blacklisted words, so, yes, that *is* what you're talking about, because they're exactly the same feature.

Comment: Related: [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so)

Answer (score 2):

As far as broadly preventing no longer needed comments... no system or user can predict all no longer needed comments. Some naturally become obsolete as situations develop. Also, "useless" isn't a currently defined category, because the balance struck for "no longer needed" was intended to be more of a "useless but benign" ([as described by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298511/178816)).

For the most part, the type of comments (aside from the obviously abusive ones) subject to one flag removal don't really pose a problem in and of themselves. Sometimes they can be pleasant (Thanks!), sometimes they can be curt (What have you tried?), but overall they are rather bland.

Removing them with a single flag allows any user who viewed the comment as problematic to simply delete it while still allowing users to say what they were going to say. It is a good middle ground.

That said, the comments are relentlessly removed by the community. More precisely, the community-*ish*, as [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy?tab=topactivity) has become a moderator and his flags are now binding so it is perhaps less obvious how many he handles/raises. Prior to election, it was at 130,593 helpful flags.

This all plays into the notion that relatively benign comments don't particularly cause a problem on their own, but if allowed to pile up do become an issue. [Shog9 addresses this in an MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298511/178816), referring to the situation as

> "Death by a thousand cuts" - one or two have an imperceptible cost, but in quantity they push the site closer to those tedious forums where finding useful information involves scanning past scores of irrelevant responses. Arguably we could just hide them and be done with it, except that no one can agree on a suitable threshold for doing it - so instead we have flags and rely on moderator judgement.

More broadly, this entire discussion we are having on automation with regards to comment prevention runs almost parallel to discussions on automation with regards to comment removal. The recent discussion [Should moderators run automated bots under their accounts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354719/1026459) does a very good job of covering many of the same aspects being examined here in this post, and the older discussion [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546/1026459) has empirical evidence as well as some in depth looks at the overall sentiment towards automating removal. While neither of these directly address *prevention*, they are nonetheless very relevant to this topic.

In my opinion, the overall problem of easy to remove comments (aside from the abusive ones) is largely solved and would not be greatly improved using a prevention tool. There are certainly other very pressing issues that the automation team should be addressing instead (ask question ux perhaps being at the top of the list).