# How to reduce number of "thanks" comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

After reading about [the featured test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction) I thought about this *big* problem more and here is my solution.

I believe comments appears because users are just trying to be nicer, more human, more friendly and don't know yet how this site is designed to work.

It should be possible to detect words like "thank" after comment is posted and then (sorry for the ugly mockup):

---

[image]

---

I hope this was not already proposed.

Comment: @toolic, I thought about it. Is it a problem to see this false-positive hint? Then we can improve detection of "thank" comment (using machine learning?). But later. After someone complains.

Comment: It gets deleted if you flag it as *"no longer needed"*. It only needs one flag. Also: [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546)

Comment: This reminds me of [this guy](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/Clippy-letter.PNG) ;-)

Comment: @adiga, what are you trying to say? Do you propose to make hint shorter by removing that moderator part? But *someone* has to flag, why not the comment poster will be the one who just delete own comment?

Comment: @BillTür, I took images from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398378/1997232). So it should be real (but I haven't seen it yet).

Comment: I think you can go to any answer of yours on main and over over the new "feature" to see the tip. Though it seems to only happen once.

Comment: this happens rarely now a days, so when only one or two are there , nobody cares, if there are a lot simply flag it and give the mods something to do

Comment: @nbk, nobody cares indeed. Except some people who think it's an issue and they have to [do something](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1997232).

Comment: Also it reminds me to comment back if they haven't accepted my answer

Comment: Dear user, please abstain from thanking anyone in comments. Thank you.

Comment: if only there were a new tool to say thanks so that we train people to say "thanks" instead of upvote....

Comment: @IanKemp Perhaps there's another reason for this implementation.. that we're not made aware of.

Comment: This may cause many "false positives", thanks to how this word is often used in the English language. But of course, I only wrote this to make clear: This would make *far* more sense than that 'SayThanks' button that they are currently wasting their (and our) time with. It's absolutely incomprehensible for me how things in the tech/management layer can go *so* dramatically wrong that *this* is the outcome.

Comment: I don't oppose this idea, but even more than with "thank you" comments, I'd like to see built-in guidance to reduce the number of "thank you" **answers**.  They come regularly and need to be pruned away manually.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477288/3744182 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477339/3744182 which both came in a few minutes before making this comment.  "thank you" answers are much more actively harmful than "thank you" comments.

Comment: False-positives are not a big problem. It's not like they're doing much. You can just close the popup and go about your day.

Comment: @Scratte 'Reactions' of multiple icons exist in Teams.

Comment: @philipxy I'm not familiar with teams. Do they also have reputation and voting?

Comment: @Scratte Re teams 'reactions' I only know [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339283/266284). Which I expected you'd find by googling 'stackexchange teams "reactions"' etc like I am about to to fill in that link.

Comment: @philipxy Thank you. It's also mentioned on the thanks-post :) It seems to not have been taken seriously enough.

Comment: @Scratte Seems there is some sort of role for satisfying less-professionally- more-socially- -oriented user phatic reactions but the way it's been introduced with SO thanks is not good & addressing it seems moot when the larger problem of wrong site use expectations & learning is not addressed. That requires better reflecting of site goals & presentation in affordances.

Comment: @philipxy I think part of the bigger problem is reflected in [this answer by deceze](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398198/12695027). And instead of addressing the problem, it's being spinned with features and UI changes.

Comment: &^%$#  I clicked the upvote button in the image ...

Comment: @rene the lack of instant popup should have been an indication.