# Lower the character limit for 'thank you' comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, thanks

I'd love to comment a simple *'Thank You'* to a well-thought-out answer. But the character minimum is 15, which means I have to type this:

> Thank you for your time and cooperation, it was greatly appreciated.

Ok, you might say upvoting an answer you liked is an alternative, though many can agree they feel better when they are awarded with an honest thank you instead of points.

It would be greatly appreciated if we either lower the minimum character count to length of "Thank You" or have an exception for the phrase "Thank you".

Comment: This limit is made to avoid such comments as “Thank you”

Comment: And stack overflow is written in C#, not python

Comment: Alright. Then what would be the best message to say Thank You.

Comment: Please note what [comments are actually for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Buddy upvote or bounty

Comment: Just suck it up, and don't write anything. I know that personally it felt odd to not indicate in comments that I'm thankful for an answer, but you'll get used to it soon enough. You'll also probably end up voting on posts more as a result, so that's a benefit.

Comment: @cigien good to know.

Comment: The best way to thank someone is by upvoting their answer! They get some rep, and the answer gets an indicator that shows it's been useful to someone :D

Comment: @Cerbrus I addressed in my question that you might say this. And I would say a thank you would be nicer. But sure, that's fine with me.

Comment: Yea, it's just something you'll need to get used to on SO

Comment: Good for you, but all you're doing is generating more work. Thanks is considered noise in comments [and posts alike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). If you actually want to show appreciation, you upvote (and accept if you're the asker). If you feel like doing something extra, [you can give them a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). A nice side-effect of bounties is that it bumps the post, which can result in more upvotes for the answerer.

Comment: Related: [the most downvoted question on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/7296893). We don't like thanks.

Comment: Kinda related: [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/6045800)

Comment: Welcome to life, where everything is hard. Except unlike life, SO is meant to be a reusable resource. Thanks has no place here in the same way general chatter has no place in an encyclopedia or just in general any other book meant to be serious and to the point.

Comment: SO is more like wikipedia than a help desk. This may explain some misconceptions. Also imagine people were allowed / encouraged to add "Thank you" to wikipedia articles and how pretty that'd look.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII - note that the reaction to the feature was not necessarily because we do not like being polite, but because SE rolled out an ill-conceived feature solving the non-existent problem and tried to force it on the public platform. P.s. That said, please, Zoe is right, don't generate more work. There is a small workaround: if you really want to say thanks, by all means, go ahead, but make the comment matter: suggest an improvement, give an off-note to a peculiar use case, etc.

Comment: see also: [How to reduce number of “thanks” comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398451/839601)

Comment: [Thank You](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Honestly I would suck it up. I totally get where you're coming from, because my reputation is high enough that I'm starting to have days where two simple words actually *do* go a longer way than an upvote/accept, but I really don't think this is one of those things that will ever change on Stack Overflow. We really want comments to be substantial, yet succinct, if they're posted at all. And the way the site has decided to do it is with a character limit with a high floor and low ceiling. It doesn't take very much to be a little specific on what you're thanking someone for, even something like "Thank you for the advice" or "Thanks for your service" would suffice to make my day here on meta.

I like the existing workflow of thanking someone, and that comment getting cleared once the recipient has seen it and it's "no longer needed" in order to declutter the comments sections. But while seasoned users value reduced clutter, new users generally don't like the idea of their comments getting deleted like that. So that's not going to work, whether we keep the character limit as is or lower it to accommodate a simple "Thank you."

I do value thank-you comments that are more than just a handful of words though. Here's what I said in [a comment elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406555/how-to-extend-my-gratitude-when-a-contributor-went-out-of-their-way-for-me/406557#comment835635_406557) the other day:

> I get some under my popular answers, appreciate the thoughtfulness that's been put into explaining how exactly I've helped or what sort of impact I've made... then check back several months or years later and find them gone, get sad about it, and sometimes even undelete them only for them to be deleted again later. It's probably the closest thing I have done to mod abuse. It never ends. I get not wanting the comments to be cluttered, but I would like to be able to keep at least one or two around, for other viewers to upvote if nothing else.

And here are some recent examples of comments I've received "explaining how exactly I've helped or what sort of impact I've made" that remind me why I do what I do on Stack Overflow:

> [Indeed a good workaround, sadly it would require me to add decimal points everywhere in my code base, so a bit of a hassle. Thanks for the suggestion, will certainly think of using this in the future instead!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971590/chrome-odd-font-size-behaviour/66971991#comment118397357_66971991)

> [this is a fantastic explanation of some very heavy (to me) reading. Thanks!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005331/is-color-format-specified-in-the-spec-for-getcomputedstyle/67006298#comment118452909_67006298)

One I just received yesterday:

> [Your responses are not merely answers but illuminating articles in themselves!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206998/apply-styles-to-nested-child-using-css-descendant-combinator-with-pseudo-class/67210327#comment118809321_67210327)

I'm not demanding that anyone go to such an extent if they really want to thank someone — what matters is they don't forget to accompany it with the appropriate upvote and/or accept vote, and that they speak their mind honestly and truthfully, not just as a pleasantry. Stack Overflow does not really value pleasantries — especially on popular answers, these *do* start to clutter up the comments quickly, and while they're nice to see every now and then, they can add up in a not-so-nice way over time.

Comment: Thank You. Your answer was greatly appreciated and well thought out.

Comment: To those who flagged, y'all should've seen what the *original* comment was.

Comment: Oh. People flagged my comment? Do they not have a sense of humor?

Comment: @BuddyBobIII: Guess not. Two of the comments I quoted have vanished, too.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII: [We hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: "...thanking someone, and that comment getting cleared once the recipient has seen it..." Finally, after wading through tons of meta stuff, I get it why several of mine and other people's comments get deleted so rapidly. I can only ask that someone would compile a list of all these useful details about stackoverflow's (internal) workings.

Comment: @SepRoland They're getting cleared mush faster now :(

Comment: @Scratte That's something I saw yesterday. I even thought that I had forgotten to click 'submit', so I retyped the damm thing only to see that it got deleted some time later.

Comment: @SepRoland Find another word. Don't mention "thank" or "thanks". There's a bot that fetches them into a chatroom and people are flagging them the instant they arrive.

Answer (score 4):

It is nice to receive thanks for hard work, but the truth is that such comments add nothing to the content. Ideally, we would have a system where a user can post a comment that automatically disappears after 15 minutes, but since we do not have anything like that, these comments can be visible for a long time.

Try to avoid adding comments that only say thanks. They are not necessary. If every user wanted to thank the poster then some posts would have thousands of comments just saying "thanks". We don't need it. If you want to show appreciation then upvote and/or accept the post.

Lowering the character limit would just make it easier to leave more meaningless comments which someone then would have to manually clean up. While comments are generally second-class citizens on this site, some of them provide valuable insight so we want them to stand out. Nobody will see a comment that is buried under many "thanks" comments.