# How to deal with users who are being abusive on valid criticism?

Tags: discussion, new-users, users, behavior

I recently came across a question which was like **How do I create something like this … ?** and the only detail was a link to a screenshot.

I commented asking the OP to be specific and post a sample code if he had tried to do something. I also referred him to the How to ask guide of Stack Overflow.

The user responds with - How could I be more specific? I provided an image of what I want to make and I am a beginner... Hope you enjoyed downvoting my question. Now go F*** yourself.

Yes, he said it. So much for being nice. I flagged the comment and it immediately disappeared. Possibly the user deleted it.

Now, there's an answer to that question referring to some other site/tutorial. I mean I understand the Be Nice policy but how do I exactly deal with such rude and abusive behaviour? It's not that the user is particularly new either. He has been here for 11 months and has asked 3 valid questions before, 2 of which were even answered. This  indicates that he has been around and is expected to be familiar with the rules. I am not pin-pointing here but a look at my recent activity would obviously find you the question I am talking about.

Comment: "Possibly the user deleted it." Assuming the censoring is in the quote, and not the actual content, then no, your flag alone would have deleted it.

Comment: You flagged the comment, the comment went away. What more are you looking for?

Comment: I suggest linking the question here. What you are describing will invite a storm of wrath on the question. Also - you were right in your response, perhaps reiterating what did the user try and why did he not post code would help.

Comment: There's zero value in linking the question here @kabanus. No point in getting vindictive.

Comment: @yannis actually I was thinking on a quality patrol perspective (If you ask about the question on meta, might as well link it), but it seems the community is much faster than my suggestions.

Comment: @yannis I honestly don't know if a comment goes away the second I flag it. I have not dealt with much abuse and this was actually the first time I saw abuse at SO.

Comment: @Servy Yeah the actual comment did not censor it. I was under the impression that a minimum no. of flags are required for automatic deletion. But yeah, since it explicitly had an abusive word, I guess you are right.

Comment: Ok. If a comment contains certain words, it'll go away with a single flag. If a user's posts or comments get more than a couple rude flags (not sure on the exact number), an automated flag will be raised inviting the site's moderators to take a closer look. We are all allowed to have a bad day, but repeat offenders will be hearing from a moderator. From your side of things, all you need to do if you happen upon someone being rude is to flag their comments.

Comment: Obviously he was offended by your unconscious bias. You should be ashamed.

Comment: @Will Yup, I am totally ashamed of myself. I should start being more biased I guess?

Comment: Why, why ever would you react negatively to being told about your failings? How could that possibly have an affect on you completely opposite of the desired one?

Comment: @will You mean I should be unbiased now? Is this a subtle reference that blog post?

Comment: Clearly you weren't being welcoming enough!

Comment: May I copy the abusive and insulting comment that you received to my post listing abusive responses from OP's ?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/758133

Comment: @MartinJames Sure you can.

Comment: @Yashovardhan done, thanks.  I'm trying to stave off all this one-sided criticism of SO curators being 'perceived as unwelcoming' by highlighting the appalling and grossly insulting comments received from OP's, such as you were umm. 'gifted with'.  I'm getting more an more convinced that any comment, no matter how nasty or nice, useful or not, constructive or not, is actually just the first username in front of the OP when they realize that they are not getting their answer and so it's all their fault.  Comment?  More like 'wear a target':(

Comment: @MartinJames I know, I was actually first excited reading that blog post but then when they started mentioning 'marginalized groups', it felt so wrong. I have never looked at the username before looking at a question/answer. I couldn't care less who the OP of a post is as long as its helping me. This was actually the first time I started curating SO, so I guess I should have expected something like this. It just feels sad that those who are actually helping maintain the quality of this site are being made feel 'unwelcome'. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Yashovardhan youi were very unfortunate to get one of 'those' OP's first time out of the box.  It's not a huge problem, but it does happen.  Carry On Curating:)

Comment: comment with f-word disappeared after your flag because the system is designed to work this way, see [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/839601)

Comment: For your future reference; I wrote this meta post to address such questions (and the people who post those kinds of comments when you respond) when I was in this exact position: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). It even has a helpful markdown snippet you can paste in a comment to them

Comment: You can reply with suggestions that are at the same level of detail as the question, giving enough help to be useful. For example, you could say "Select the "New WPF Form option in Visual Studio" and then provide a link to the MS "Hello World WPF page.

You're certainly not obligated to put in a lot more effort for the answer than the OP put into the question, but OTOH, you can always be nice, especially because there's no reason to ever be "not nice". It's counterproductive in both tech and business relationships.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Downvote, Flag, and **Walk Away**.

Any response, even if you *somehow* manage to make your response helpful and relevant, it just invites another abusive response.

Therefore, any attempt you make at "dealing with abuse" (other than the prior suggestion) will result in more noise and more nonsense that the moderators have to "deal with" later.

I appreciate that you would want to help such a toxic person, but you might find that trying to do so through Stack Overflow is counter-productive. If he or she refuses to clarify the question, the question should be flagged and/or voted to close with no further attempts at asking him or her to clarify.

Comment: One of my personal attempts of pointing a toxic OP to the be nice policy (around 1 year ago) only led the user to repeat the offensive comment. So yes, it's best to stay away.

Comment: The issue there is that we are then told we are elitist because we donwvote without saying why.... Seems like a problem without a solution

Comment: @Patrice that's pretty much expected when the problem is someone being toxic and unreasonable ;) The only issue that I see is that you leave it as a trap for the next nice person wanting to help to fall into, until the flag is handled. Not much to be done about that either I guess.

Comment: The problem is that a number of the newbs then get flagged for terrible questions/attitudes and as we all know theres a "SO isnt nice to newbs" thing going round.. so then we are seen as hostile

Comment: @BugFinder That notion that's going around is nonsense. The website has all these tools that we can use with documentation on what they mean. If the tools can't exist without comments, they should be deleted altogether. If the author of that blog post wants to start a personal coding help service, rather than a Q&A website, he should do it.

Answer (score 13):

Flag it, vent to a friend... and then let it go!

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I think you did exactly what you were suppose to do.  What we need is the ability to route a question like this through the same sort of help that beginners (hopefully) will be getting, where someone helps them ask the question better (a problem we already know about).  The standard "learn to ask better questions" response makes people defensive and causes this sort of behavior, and thus we get a bad reputation.  "Be Nice" doesn't work when we have no better answer then "Learn to ask questions correctly".

Comment: maybe adding "learn to search" would help or make it worse, too